# Tincr chrome extension won't save file changes

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I installed the [Tincr Chrome extension](http://tin.cr) so I can edit CSS directly via the Chrome DevTools. The extension claims to work both ways. If I change the CSS-File in Aptana the browser refreshes automatically (this works great). However, if I make changes to the CSS via the DevTools Elements-tab, the file doesn't get saved, so the changes are lost as soon as I hit F5.

Tincr Configuration:

```
Project Type: Http Web Server 
Auto-Save enabled
```

Ressource

```
style.css 
URL: /tincrtest/style.css 
File Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\tincrtest\style.css
```

I also run Chrome (v28) as an Administrator (Win7/32).

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I also have this problem, but isn't stackoverflow supposed to be for coding questions, not software support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem with Tincr 
But you can change in your files (css/js) using DevTool and save your changes to source file 
by using workspaces 
you need just choose project or folder which contain your files

this two videos explain workspaces:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVSo4buDAEE

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6qe_kVaBpg